# What does "eq^~" mean in Coq?

Tags: coq

When I write
'Print Qeq_trans.' in the CoqIde, I can see many 'eq^~' expressions in message window.

For example, eq^~ (Qnum z * QDen x * QDen y)%Z.

Please let me know the meaning of this term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a way to apply a function to only its second argument. Do a

```
Locate "_ ^~ _".
```

to get the definition.

Comment: Indeed, `f^~x` is `fun y => f y x`